# Blazor wasm InputFile wont work in mobile

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, memorystream

Blazor wasm Input File wont work in mobile but in browser it works perfectly.

This is the Blazor Page

```html
<div class="mb-3">
<InputFile OnChange="OnFileChanged" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg" capture></InpuFile>
</div>
```

This is my method InputFile OnChange that convert image file to base 64

```
async Task OnFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
  {

  try{

    foreach(var img in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
    {
        IBrowserFile file = img;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.OpenReadStream(1024000).CopyToAsync(ms);
            byte[] somBytes = ms.ToArray();
            var qrCodeData = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("readQRCodeFromBase64",     Convert.ToBase64String(somBytes));
            BarcodeRead(qrCodeData);
           model.StringImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(somBytes, 0, somBytes.Length);
            
             if (model.fileTosave != null) hasFiles = true;
               loading = false;
              }
        }
     }
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you tell what exactly doesn't work? Does the file not upload, does it throw an exception or does it return the wrong value...

Comment: i found out that the image that i upload in mobile the file size is 4mb, memorystream can read up to 512kb, correct me if im wrong, i tried to reduce image file size to 200kb then it work.